# Ruby: how to make an array of words, with the length of the array being random

Tags: ruby

I use the excellent [faker gem](https://github.com/stympy/faker) to generate random words for my models. Eg. `product.name = Faker::Lorem.word`

Sometimes I need to generate a sentence, and I want the length of the sentence to 
vary each time.

How to achieve this with ruby?

Comment: you want to make array of strings?

Comment: It helps to break these things down. First you need a random number that indicates how many times you want to run the function. Then you need to run a loop that many times in which you call the function. Each of these steps is fairly trivial and will get you to Uri's answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:

```
result = rand(max_size).times.map { produce_word }
```

Comment: this is what i was looking for, for my seeds.rb

Answer (score 0):

Since you have not provided enough information, this is my approach, `[*1..100].sample` will return a random number between 1 and 100, so looping that times the string which is returned bya  method named `get_word` will get stored in the array `word_array`

```
word_array = []
[*1..100].sample.times do
  word_array << get_word
end
```